# Code and Inputs on to use AWS temporary Credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am adding below code for review as i am bit new to boto3. This Script adds tags (key and value) to All Volumes of EC2 listed in Excel. Is there any more effective way i could have written this? Also I am using AWS temporary credentials by editing ~/aws/config and making profiles. Is there any other way i can use w.r.t login with temporary credentials in boto3 ?

```py
def tagging(profilename):

    print("")
    print("Using Profile: {}".format(profilename))
    print("")
    path = input("Please enter the full path of Excel to execute: ")
    wb=load_workbook('Data_TagVolumes.xlsx')
    Sheet1 = wb.active
    max_row=Sheet1.max_row
    max_column=Sheet1.max_column
    Tag_Key = Sheet1.cell(2,1).value
    Tag_Value = Sheet1.cell(2,2).value
    print("")
    print("All Volumes of each Below EC2 Servers will be Tagged:")
    print("")
    tag_vm = []
    for each in range(2,max_row+1):
        print("{}".format(Sheet1.cell(each,3).value))
        tag_vm.append(Sheet1.cell(each,3).value)
    print("")
    print("With Tag Key as : {}".format(Tag_Key))
    print("")
    print("And Tag Value as : {}".format(Tag_Value))
    print("")
    confirm = input("Please Confirm Yes to proceed or No to exit: ").lower()
    print("")
    if confirm == 'yes':
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profilename)        
        ec2 = session.client('ec2')
        tag_vol = []
        for vm in tag_vm: 
            response = ec2.describe_instances(
                Filters=[
                            {
                            'Name': 'tag:Name',
                            'Values': [vm]
                            },
                        ],
                    )
            for each in list(range(len(response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['BlockDeviceMappings']))):
                vm_vol = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['BlockDeviceMappings'][each]['Ebs']['VolumeId']
                print("{}   {}".format(vm,vm_vol))
                tag_vol.append(vm_vol)
        ec2.create_tags(Resources= tag_vol,
            Tags=[
                    {
                    'Key': Tag_Key,
                    'Value': Tag_Value
                    },
                ]
            )
        print("")
        print("All Volumes Tagged. please validate on AWS Console")
        print("")
    else:
        print("")
        print ("OK Exited")
        print("")

     def main():
       profilename = input("Please enter aws credentials profile name: ")
       tagging(profilename)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```